# How often I need to change the motor oil of the Honda Fit 2008?

Tags: honda, oil, oil-change, motors, fit

I bought a Honda Fit 2008 with 53000 miles, and I want to know how often I need change the motor oil?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've upvoted your question, it is a good first question in to the ownership of any car. I'm glad you're planning on taking good care of your car. Not everyday we get to answer to new owners who are willing to learn and self serve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ALL newer Honda cars come with an "oil life" measuring system, which tells the driver when to change the oil. This system is better than using a schedule in two ways...

- It prevents you from changing the oil too soon, which is a waste of money and doesn't extend the life of the engine at all.
- It warns you of situations where you might need to change your oil *earlier* than the scheduled time, which saves you money because it can prevent engine damage due to "used" oil that needs to be changed.

Use this system, it is good. This is the only right answer for a Honda, really.
(I checked - the 2008 Fit does have this system)

Comment: thanks, I investigated more and this is a good answer, I only recommend to everybody always stay alert of the levels and conditions of the oil, just to add extra care to the car.

Comment: MY Honda Fit 2008 doesnt come with any system. No lights, no nothing. I have to follow shcedule.

Comment: It's not an idiot light - it's on your multi-function display. You can see the indicator in this video (of a 2008 Fit) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehqLWA4nCeI

BTW, if you've never seen that, you're probably changing the oil too soon and wasting money.

Comment: I'm agree with @Jasmine, you can press the Trip button and the Oil Life will come to the small screen. I recently changed the Oil because the light of maintenance turned on.

Answer (score 4):

Your owner's manual should contain a maintenance schedule, or you could have a separate maintenance schedule booklet included with the packet that contains your owner's manual.

If you don't have your owner's manual, the internet says your interval is 7500 miles. Also note that you should change your filter when you change your oil.

Answer (score 1):

Buy Idemitsu fully synthetic SN 0w20 for any region. Change at 5000 mileage or 6 months (whichever is earlier). Use only genuine Honda filter for proper oil pressure handling. Earlier Mobil was the supplier with added Zddp, now Idemitsu has taken up the contract.

Please do not buy Redline, no matter what the performance benefits are. It lacks the additives required to cover the engine components with a protective layer.

I hope you understand and appreciate these intervals. These are created by Honda, you'll find the same at your local Honda dealership.

Comment here if you'd like to know more.

Good luck and congratulations on your Honda ownership still solid at 53K mileage.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Oil Change intervals in motorcycle is between 2500–3000KMs depending on your riding style.
You can get 3000+km oil change interval for someone who rides mostly below 50–70 kmh
But if you rides mostly above 100kmh change your oil between 2000–2500km.

Comment: It looks like this is a car...

Comment: While this maybe so, the question is clearly about a car.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2007 Honda Fit with 221 K miles. Only use full syn. engine oil and change every 7K miles . Bought it with 62K mi. it doesnt burn a drop between changes. Do run it once a year on 1000 mi. trip and runs like a dream . ( although the RPMs are high ). Great car and hoping for another 100K mi. Mobil 1 5W20 is best oil money can buy at the retail level. Been using it for 20 years in all vehicles with excellent results .

Comment: Is this answer based on the user manual? If it is not, how has it deviated from it and why? I think that feeling in such details would remarkably improve your answer! Is the viscosity same as detailed in the manual? Apply the same logic to the time frame (oil change interval)? Does the manual dictate conventional or synthetic?